# MouseLeftButtonDown animation activates very late when clicking control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

Hi I have a strange problem in my WPF project.
I'm trying to style some elements on my UI and I also want to implement animations like click animations or hover animations.
There were no problems when creating any of these animations except for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` animation.

In my style I implemented the animation like this (this `Style` is for `Label`s):

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                <ColorAnimation To="#6A6A6A" Duration="0:0:0.04" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

My expectation was that the `Foreground` of the `Label` changes to #6A6A6A whenever I press the left mouse button.
In fact it does what I expected but the animation doesn't get executed immediately but about 1 second after I pressed the left mouse button (lmb pressed -> waiting for 1 sec -> color changes).
I really don't know why this happens. All the other animations work fine and are executed immediately as they should except for this one.
I tried to change the color of the `Label` via an event in the code-behind because I thought there might be an error with my XAML code but the result was the same delayed animation.

What can I do to the desired result?

Comment: Try `Duration="00:00:00"`

Comment: tried this already but unfortunately with so success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from this very simple working example, it is something in *your* code that is causing your problem:

```
<TextBlock Text="Oh I don't know... just some text">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Nobody can tell you what your problem is because you haven't shown the relevant code... please don't take this sentence to mean *add all of your code to your question*... that is *not* what it means. If you want further help with this problem, then please carefully follow the good advice given in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page of the Stack Overflow Help Center to provide a *complete, but concise, working code example that still exhibits your problem*.

When following this simplification advice, 9 out of 10 times we can often find a solution to our problem anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Well, I feel like an idiot if I have to try such simple things :D I really don't know why it does not work in my application. I setup a new project to test your code and I even knew that it worked. Argh.. So yeah in the new project it worked fine and I copied my code to the new project too. And yeah it worked too. I think I'll do some rework on my application maybe I'll find out why it doesn't work.